# call a method of the binding class from a button click xamarin.

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding, xamarin

So i have a View that i have bound to a List of Timer objects called Timers (custom class i have made), and in the view i have added a start and remove button. when a user clicks start i want them to be able to call the relevant timer object method startTimer() associated with the button. How can i do this?

View code:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Timers, Mode=TwoWay}" SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackLayout Padding="10,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Text="{Binding _name, Mode=TwoWay}" YAlign="Center"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding _startTime, Mode=TwoWay}" YAlign="Center" FontSize="Small"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <Button Text="Start" //button to associate with method//></Button>
                    <Button Text="Remove"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<Button Text="Add New" Clicked="AddNewTimer"/>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

My Binded Class:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel ()
    {
        Timers = DependencyService.Get<ISaveAndLoad> ().LoadTimers (); 
        if (Timers == null) {
            Timers = new ObservableCollection<Timer> (); 
        }
    }

    //When property changes notifys everything using it. 
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Timer> _timers;
    public ObservableCollection<Timer> Timers { 
        get { return _timers; } 
        set { 
            _timers = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged ("Timers");
        } 
    }

    private string _title;
    public string Title{ 
        get{ 
            return _title; 
        }
        set{ 
            _title = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged ();
        }
    }
}
```

And the timer class:

```
    public class Timer
{ 
    public int _startTime { get; set;} 
    public bool _hasStarted{ get; set; } 
    public string _name { get; set; }  

    public Timer (string name, int startTime, bool hasStarted = false)
    {
        _name = name; 
        _startTime = startTime; 
        _hasStarted = hasStarted; 
    }

    public void startTimer(){
        //do something here
    }
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your View XAML code you should add this to your start button:

```
<Button Text="Start" Command={Binding btnStartCommand} />
```

Then on your "My Binded Class: " you should create de ICommand property and initialize it on the constructor and then create the Command, something like this:

```
public ICommand btnStartCommand {get; set;}
public MainViewModel()
{
    btnStartCommand = new Command(StartCommand);
}
public void StartCommand()
{
    //here you create your call to the startTimer() method
}
```

Hope this helps you,
 Cheers.